# Android videoView not showing inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-videoview

Hey all I am having a little bit of an issue with trying to call a fragment that has the videoview within it into my current fragment page.

When I click on the test button I set up it goes through the code without error but never shows the video fragment - I even gave it a background color of red so I could see it load into my current view.

My goal here is just to send a parameter of the video path to the video fragment videoview player and start playing it.

**videoPlay.java**

```
public class videoPlay extends Fragment {
    public videoPlay(){
    //constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout._fragvideoplay, container, false);

        MediaController mc= new MediaController(getActivity());
        VideoView view = (VideoView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString() + "/sddir/Bubble Guppies.mp4";
        view.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        view.setMediaController(mc);
        view.start();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}
```

**_fragvideoplayer.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**FragMovies.java:**

```
public class FragMovies extends Fragment {

    public FragMovies(){
    //constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout._fragmovies, container, false);
        WebView view = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView);

        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                container.findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                container.findViewById(R.id.pBar1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                container.findViewById(R.id.pBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                container.findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

        view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        view.loadUrl("https://www.bing.com/");

        return rootView ;
    }
}
```

**_fragmovies.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pBar1"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="950px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="950px" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main_activity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getViews();

        //adapter setup
        pagerAdapter = new com.example.telluridetainment.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //attaching fragments to adapter
        pagerAdapter.addFragment(new FragMovies(),"Movies");

        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        //setting icons
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_movie_white_24dp);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
        button.setOnClickListener(new MyClass());
    }

    public class MyClass implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            videoPlay myfragment = new videoPlay();
            //pass data
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("KEY","DATA");
            myfragment.setArguments(bundle);

            FragmentTransaction fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentManager.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);

            fragmentManager.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentManager.replace(R.id.viewPager, myfragment).commit();
        }

    }

    private void getViews() {
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.mTabLayout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="2000px"
    android:layout_height="1200px"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:textColor="#B71C1C" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/appbarLayout"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The path to the movie is correct. And the movie is there in the "external" SD card path. Clicking around on the new fragment (videoPlay) yields no video menu (play, remind, pause...) so its not there.

Any help would be great!

Comment: try to minimize the problem . add a small video file in assets/raw and play it in `VideoView` if that works then there might be some path of permission related issue with your code .